# How can I show this grammar is ambiguous?

Tags: language-concepts

```
T-->iSS |iS
S--> n | T
```

I tried to show like this

```
T->iSS->inS->inn
T->iS->iT->iiSS->iinS->iinn
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
T
iS
iT
iiSS
iinn

T
iSS
iTS
iiSS             
iinn
```